# Unable to test React propType with custom validator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I’m using jest with react-testing-library to test a component that has a custom prop-types validator. The validator looks like this:

```js
aspectRatio: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    const value = props[propName];
    const cleaned = value
        .trim()
        .replace(/[^0-9:]+/g, ''); // Replace everything but numbers and forward slash.

    // Ensure value is “number/number”.
    const isCorrectFormat = /^\d+:\d+$/.test(cleaned);

    if (!isCorrectFormat) {
        return new Error(`Invalid value format “${value}” supplied to “${propName}” prop in “${componentName}” component. Expected something like “3:2”.`);
    }
},
```

My test looks like this:

```js
test('throws error when incorrect aspect ratio format passed', () => {
    expect(() => {
        render(
            <Picture
                alt="Hello, picture."
                aspectRatio="1-1/8"
                src="test/books.jpg"
            />,
        );
    }).toThrowError();
});
```

The validator works as expected when rendering a faulty `aspectRatio`. I get the following error in the console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid value format “1-1/8” supplied to “aspectRatio” prop in “Picture” component. Expected something like “3:2”.
```

But when running the above test, I get this message in the terminal:

```
  ● throws error when incorrect aspect ratio format passed

    expect(received).toThrowError()

    Received function did not throw

      81 |          />,
      82 |      );
    > 83 |  }).toThrowError();
         |     ^
      84 |  spy.mockRestore();
      85 | });
      86 |
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Logging an error is not the same as *throwing* an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the propType validator doesn’t actually `throw`, I was able to resolve by testing for `console.warn` content.

```js
test('throws error when incorrect aspect ratio format passed', () => {
    console.error = jest.fn();
    render(
        <Picture
            alt="Hello, picture."
            aspectRatio="1-1/8"
            src="test/books.jpg"
        />,
    );
    expect(console.error.mock.calls[0][2]).toBe('Invalid value format “1-1/8” supplied to “aspectRatio” prop in “Picture” component. Expected something like “3:2”.');
});
```